# Repositioning Font awesome Icons

Tags: html, css

Right now it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtpAl.jpg).

The html I have right now is

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay=".1s"></i>
                <p><a class="email specialcolor" href="mailto:sales@higherpromos.com">sales@higherpromos.com</a></p>
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook fa-pull-left wow bounceIn social"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter fa-pull-left wow bounceIn social"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-google-plus fa-pull-left wow bounceIn social"></i>
            </div>
```

There is currently no CSS. I am wanting the facebook, google plus, and twitter logos to be centered in between the phone number and email address. I got it close by adding the fa-pull-left to the class, but its not exactly right....

Comment: It doesnt look like your code resembles what the image displays. Can you paste the code that is used to produce the image?

Comment: That is the code in the picture. I just screenshot what is showing on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needed a better implementation of Bootstrap classes. And separating your elements individually. (2 columns of 6 span, and 1 full width centered content column) by using the following classes:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center">
<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
```

**EDIT**

Should the classes be too large, you can reduce the size of the columns and use the -push-* classes to adjust accordingly without loosing any responsiveness in other devices and avoiding unnecessary position absolutes, floats, or large margins.

The demo is edited to show this concept. The divs in this case woudl look like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-2 text-center">
<div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-push-1 text-center">
```

Here is the [**demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLgBxx) in more detail

Comment: That is spreading out the phone number and email address too much. I like the positioning of that, I just need to move the icons over.

Comment: That's becasue I used col-md-6 which it splits the screen in 2 exact halves. But you can use a smaller size. from 1 to 12. I'm not sure which one you'd like best. Now, keep in mind, you may have to use some col-md-push-* or col-md-offset-* to center it again

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Now my next problem is our twitter feed, is hiding it all. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B60t5hh9qJrfY1pvOW93TGIyQ2M any idea how to fix that? I am wanting that to be in line with the rest of the text on the left, and to put a couple of linked pictures on the left side. Sorry for all the questions! I'm totally new at this!

Comment: @JenniferSturgis Glad it worked! First mark this as an answer for others that may see this. ANd open a new question with the twitter problem and relevant code and I'll go look at it right away